# Usage of npm scala-node

Tags: node.js, scala

I want to use scala object in node js as one of the modules. After some investigation, I found this npm plugin called [scala-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scala-node) (not sure if this will work).

But I don't know how to use it. It would be helpful if I get few examples if someone has used it to understand the functioning of this plugin.

Answer (score 1):

How much do you want this library?

`scala-node` is for node interop with [`scala.js`](http://www.scala-js.org/), which is another "compile to js" project, this time using scala. If you manage to compile this scala library with scala.js (may be a headache, depending on its dependencies). You might then need `scala-node` to modularize the compile scala.js? Not sure.

Probably be easier to have an application in scala that your node.js application communicates with. What library are you wanting to take advantage of?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer! Well I have this one file in scala.js with an object which I want to use in my node application as one of the node modules. I see the complications, now that you have mentioned using the scald-node :( It could be helpful if I could get a way around to use the scala object in node in some way, or an example for scala-node(just as a ray of hope).